# Rspecのexpectメソッドを使い回したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Rspecを用いてテストコードを書いているのですが、複数のitで同じexpectを使用するのでどこかに定義してそれをメソッドのように各itに定義して使いたいのです。
思ったような記事が見つからず困っています。
開発の現場ではこのような場合どのようにdryにしているのか気になります。

下記の `expect(テストしたい値).to eq 1` が何度も登場して `expect(テストしたい値).to eq 2` というように今後どんどん増えるので定義場所を一か所にして記述時の負担と見落としを減らしたいと考えています。

詳しい方、教えていただきたいです。お願いいたします。

```
it '権限Aで値が返る' do
  expect(テストしたい値).to eq 1
end

it '権限Bで値が返る' do
  expect(テストしたい値).to eq 1
end

it '権限Cで値が返る' do
  expect(テストしたい値).to eq 1
end
```

Answer (score 2):

shared_examples を使えば共通化は出来ますが記述量が減るかどうかは微妙ですね
テストはあえてDRYにしないやり方の方が扱いやすい場合が多いと思います

```rb
describe do
  shared_examples "value is 1" do
    it do
      expect(expected).to eq 1
    end
  end

  context do
    let(:expected) { 1 }
    include_examples "value is 1"
  end

  context do
    let(:expected) { 1 }
    include_examples "value is 1"
  end
end
```

Comment: [How I can use one Rspec expect assertion to be run for every test, without repeating myself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151885/how-i-can-use-one-rspec-expect-assertion-to-be-run-for-every-test-without-repea)ありがとうございます。ここでhelperに書く方法を提示している方がいるのですが、そのやり方はあまり使用されないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

要件に合うかどうかわかりませんが、[rspec-parameterized](https://github.com/tomykaira/rspec-parameterized) gem というのを使うと次のように書けます。

```rb
describe do
  where(:condition, :expected) do
    [
      ['a', 1],
      ['b', 2],
      ['c', 3],
    ]
  end
  with_them do
    it do
      expect(hoge(condition)).to eq expected
    end
  end
end
# expect(hoge('a')).to eq 1
# expect(hoge('b')).to eq 2
# expect(hoge('c')).to eq 3
# と同じ
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。これでも代用出来そうです。ただgemを新たに追加するのは難しそうなので `shared_examples` で実装してみようと思います。 [DRY controller specs with RSpec: repeated expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887183/dry-controller-specs-with-rspec-repeated-expect)